# How can I creat struct view in SwiftUI

Tags: generics, swiftui

I want to use QuestionView View in two different View. But I have Questions array in 1st View. 2. I have WrongQuestions array in View. I'm passing these arrays into QuestionView with @Binding. I don't want to write the same QuestionView twice. I just want to change the @Binding arrays it will get.

I have two different models. 1. `Question` 2. `WrongQuestion`

How can I design QuestionView according to these two different models?

I don't want QuestionView to only get `[Question]` array. I want it to retrieve `[Question]` and `[WrongQuestion]` arrays.

First I want to show QuestionView

I want `@Binding var questions: [Question]` array in QuestionView to have WrongQuestions in second View. How can I do that ?

**QuestionView:**

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    
    @State var selectedQuestion: Int = 1
    @StateObject var questionConfig = QuestionConfig()
    @Binding var questions: [Question] //
    
    var body: some View {
       ...........
    }
}
```

**1. View:**

**QuizCategoryViewModel:**

```
final class QuizCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
       .....
    @Published var selectedQuestion: [Question] = []
       .....
}


struct QuizCategoryView: View {
    
    @StateObject var quizCategoryViewModel: QuizCategoryViewModel = QuizCategoryViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ......
        QuestionView(questions: $quizCategoryViewModel.selectedQuestion)
        ......
    }
}
```

**2. View:**

**WrongQuestionView:**

As seen in the second View it wants me to assign [Question] array, but I want to assign [WrongQuestion] array here. How can I make this generic?

```
struct WrongQuestionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        QuestionView(questions: <#T##[Question]#>) <---- HERE
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be some detail missing in the question (like showing `Question` and `WrongQuestion` and where the view is that has the array of `WrongQuestion`), but in a general sense, it sounds like you need a `protocol` that both `Question` and `WrongQuestion` conform to and then a `QuestionView` that can accept either type.

```
protocol QuestionType {
    
}

struct Question : QuestionType {
    
}

struct WrongQuestion : QuestionType {
    
}

struct QuestionView<T:QuestionType>: View {
    @Binding var questions: [T]
    
    var body: some View {
       Text("Hi")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var wrongQuestions : [WrongQuestion] = []
    @State var questions : [Question] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        QuestionView(questions: $wrongQuestions)
        QuestionView(questions: $questions)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have better naming for protocol? because you used `QuestionType` this could be good fit for struct, for protocol maybe would be `QuestionProtocol`? any other idea?

Comment: @swiftPunk It's a matter of personal preference. I like `QuestionType` because the protocol describes the restrictions of the type. If you like `QuestionProtocol`, that works as well.